# Load a partial view asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working on one page checkout system in asp.net core I am using a partial view for each the stages of course I no you can just use below, but I want to load the partial view on button click of checkout it will show stage 2 etc and hide stage 1. I no the question may have been ask before but I am using the new asp.net core and was wondering what is the best practise for it.

> @Html.Partial("_checkoutStage1.cshtml");
>
> @Html.Partial("_checkoutStage2.cshtml") ;

Which will render a partrial view but what I want to be able to do is click a button to show stage two.

I found a bit of javascript and tried it with this being in my main view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#loadPartialView").click(function () {
    $.get('@Url.Action("LoadStage2", "Basket")', {}, function (response) {
        $("#Display").html(response);
    });
});
</script>
```

My Button

```
<button id="search"  class="btn btn-success">Checkout <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span> 
</button>
```

My Controller which is in my basket controller. Another question I have can you move the partial views to another directory or is ~/views/basket/ _ underscore prefix the correct naming convention for partial views.

```
public ActionResult LoadStage2(string searchText)
 {
  
        return PartialView("~/Views/Basket/_checkoutStage2.cshtml");
 }
```

Head of my layout page

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
     
</head>
```

Can someone help me out with this obv we dont want the page to refresh so I need to place it in a div on the button click.

**My Index.cshtml based on basket layout**

```
@model List<solitudedccore.models.basket.basketlines>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_BasketLayout.cshtml";
}

<head>
     
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#checkout").click(function () {
    $.get('@Url.Action("LoadStage2", "Basket")', {}, function (response) {
        $("#Display").html(response);
    });
});
    </script>


</head>

@Html.Partial("_checkoutStage1.cshtml");


<div  id="Display"></div>
```

**Full basketlayout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <script>

  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 
  
        @RenderBody()
 
</body>
</html>
```

Checkout stage 1 includes the button which I want to load stage 2 from it might be my misunderstanding of page cycle coming from 15 years of web forms.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Price</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Total</th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                            <div class="media">
                                <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-2/72/product-icon.png" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Product name</a></h4>
                                    <h5 class="media-heading"> by <a href="#">Brand name</a></h5>
                                    <span>Status: </span><span class="text-success"><strong>In Stock</strong></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="3">
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>$4.87</strong></td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>$14.61</strong></td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="media">
                                <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-2/72/product-icon.png" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Product name</a></h4>
                                    <h5 class="media-heading"> by <a href="#">Brand name</a></h5>
                                    <span>Status: </span><span class="text-warning"><strong>Leaves warehouse in 2 - 3 weeks</strong></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="2">
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-1 text-center"><strong>$4.99</strong></td>
                        <td class="col-md-1 text-center"><strong>$9.98</strong></td>
                        <td class="col-md-1">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td><h5>Subtotal</h5></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><h5><strong>$24.59</strong></h5></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td><h5>Estimated shipping</h5></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><h5><strong>$6.94</strong></h5></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td><h3>Total</h3></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><h3><strong>$31.53</strong></h3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Continue Shopping
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            

                            <button id="checkout"  class="btn btn-success">Checkout <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span> 
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="detailsDiv" class="detailsDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, if you want to show Stage 2 by clicking on the button, your click listener would need to be bound to the $('#search') button. In your code you are binding a click event to $('#loadPartialView'), which you don't show anywhere.

You also need to do a bit of debugging to see exactly where the issue is. You've posted some code, but you don't indicate what exactly is happening with the current code. Does the partial view get returned through the get successfully? Is the click listener firing?

You could put a breakpoint on the line

```
$("#Display").html(response);
```

and see if response has any contents. Presumably they should be HTML.

Regarding your second question about naming conventions of partial views. Typically if a partial view is used across controllers, I put it in /Shared. But if it is only used within one controller (seems like your case) putting the partial within the controller folder is fine. Yes, the _ is the proper convention for naming partials.

Comment: I tried that but no luck I cant even set a brake point on that line for some reason im running 2017 community I have incldued more of my files in last edit to see if can pin point the issue